# Router: Show component based on access with same route path

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a `home` route which is used by both an admin and a user, is there a way where I can show `UserComponent` if you are logged in as a user, and show `AdminComponent` if you are logged in as an admin?

This is what I currently have:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
  {
    path: 'home',
    component: HomeComponent,
    children: [
      // Children routes mix of user/admin paths
    ]
  }
]
```

What I was thinking is that maybe I could do something like this, however, I don't know how to access the service at this point in the script.

```
component: this.userService.isAdmin ? AdminComponent : UserComponent,
```

Comment: I would suggest having a wrapper component assigned to that route and check service state with a ngIf to render relevant component rather than trying to have dynamic route assignment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this in HomeComponent:

HTML:

```
<admin-component *ngIf="isAdmin; else userHome;"></admin-component>
<ng-template #userHome>
    <user-component></user-component>
</ng-template>
```

TS:

```
class HomeComponent {
    public isAdmin: boolean;

    constructor(userService: UserService) {
         this.isAdmin = userService.isAdmin;
    }
}
```